# Scene2d | Calling rotateBy on 30 Actors causes low fps on android

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a game where my objects are constantly rotating around a center point. The problem is that when I call rotateBy on more than 20 actors at once, the fps drops from 60 fps to 30. Is this normal behavior? How can rotating 30 actors cause such drop in fps?

EDIT : I should also metion that each actor has a body, and the fixtures are destroyed and re created each frame (Because the actors change size).

EDIT here is the code, this is called each frame for each actor.

```
private void createFixtures(boolean remove) {

    if (remove) {
        if (fixture_inner != null) {
            if (body.getFixtureList().contains(fixture_inner, false)) {
                body.destroyFixture(fixture_inner);
            }
        }
        if (fixture_outer != null) {
            if (body.getFixtureList().contains(fixture_outer, false)) {
                body.destroyFixture(fixture_outer);
            }
        }
        if (fixture_gap != null) {
            if (body.getFixtureList().contains(fixture_gap, false)) {
                body.destroyFixture(fixture_gap);
            }
        }
        if (fixture_innerCircle != null) {
            if (body.getFixtureList().contains(fixture_innerCircle, false)) {
                body.destroyFixture(fixture_innerCircle);
            }
        }
        if (fixture_outerCircle != null) {
            if (body.getFixtureList().contains(fixture_outerCircle, false)) {
                body.destroyFixture(fixture_outerCircle);
            }
        }
    }

    if (getInnerBounds() != null) {
        FixtureDef fixtureDef_inner = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape_inner = new PolygonShape();
        shape_inner.set(getInnerBounds().getTransformedVertices());
        fixtureDef_inner.shape = shape_inner;
        fixtureDef_inner.filter.categoryBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_BLOCKER;
        fixtureDef_inner.filter.maskBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_PLAYER;
        fixtureDef_inner.isSensor = true;
        fixture_inner = body.createFixture(fixtureDef_inner);
        BlockerFixtureUserData fixtureUserData_inner = new BlockerFixtureUserData(this, gameObjects.indexOf(this, false));
        fixture_inner.setUserData(fixtureUserData_inner);
        shape_inner.dispose();

    }

    if (getInnerCircleBounds() != null) {
        FixtureDef fixtureDef_circle = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape_circle = new PolygonShape();
        shape_circle.set(getInnerCircleBounds().getTransformedVertices());
        fixtureDef_circle.shape = shape_circle;
        fixtureDef_circle.filter.categoryBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_BLOCKER;
        fixtureDef_circle.filter.maskBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_PLAYER;
        fixtureDef_circle.isSensor = true;
        fixture_innerCircle = body.createFixture(fixtureDef_circle);
        BlockerFixtureUserData fixtureUserData_circle = new BlockerFixtureUserData(this, gameObjects.indexOf(this, false));
        fixture_innerCircle.setUserData(fixtureUserData_circle);
        shape_circle.dispose();
    }

    if (getOuterCircleBounds() != null) {
        FixtureDef fixtureDef_circle = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape_circle = new PolygonShape();
        shape_circle.set(getOuterCircleBounds().getTransformedVertices());
        fixtureDef_circle.shape = shape_circle;
        fixtureDef_circle.filter.categoryBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_BLOCKER;
        fixtureDef_circle.filter.maskBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_PLAYER;
        fixtureDef_circle.isSensor = true;
        fixture_outerCircle = body.createFixture(fixtureDef_circle);
        BlockerFixtureUserData fixtureUserData_circle = new BlockerFixtureUserData(this, gameObjects.indexOf(this, false));
        fixture_outerCircle.setUserData(fixtureUserData_circle);
        shape_circle.dispose();
    }

    if (getOuterBounds() != null) {
        FixtureDef fixtureDef_outer = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape_outer = new PolygonShape();
        shape_outer.set(getOuterBounds().getTransformedVertices());
        fixtureDef_outer.shape = shape_outer;
        fixtureDef_outer.filter.categoryBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_BLOCKER;
        fixtureDef_outer.filter.maskBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_PLAYER;
        fixtureDef_outer.isSensor = true;
        fixture_outer = body.createFixture(fixtureDef_outer);
        BlockerFixtureUserData fixtureUserData_outer = new BlockerFixtureUserData(this, gameObjects.indexOf(this, false));
        fixture_outer.setUserData(fixtureUserData_outer);

        shape_outer.dispose();
    }

    if (getGapBounds() != null) {
        FixtureDef fixtureDef_gap = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape_gap = new PolygonShape();
        shape_gap.set(getGapBounds().getTransformedVertices());
        fixtureDef_gap.shape = shape_gap;
        fixtureDef_gap.filter.categoryBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_BLOCKERGAP;
        fixtureDef_gap.filter.maskBits = Config.CATEGORYBIT_PLAYER;
        fixtureDef_gap.isSensor = true;
        fixture_gap = body.createFixture(fixtureDef_gap);
        BlockerFixtureUserData fixtureUserData_gap = new BlockerFixtureUserData(this, gameObjects.indexOf(this, false));
        fixture_gap.setUserData(fixtureUserData_gap);

        shape_gap.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your actors drawing UI elements with Drawables, or are you drawing TextureRegions directly? Some Scene2d.UI elements cause batch flushes for each Actor when rotated. If your elements are not UI elements, avoid the Drawable classes and draw TextureRegions directly. I don't have experience with Box2D to know if what you're doing there is a heavy action. Do avoid using the Java `new` keyword in your render loop, as that is likely to incur a lot of garbage collection.

Comment: @Tenfour04 My actors are using a sprite to render

Comment: Please show some code. Specifically the creation and rotation methods.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you destroy and recreate the fixtures every single frame, you will be doing this about `1800` times every second. Instead of destroying and recreating every frame, you could destroy and recreate fixtures independently of your framerate (ie. 10 times per second, which will equate to 300 times per second for 30 actors).

This will significantly reduce the amount of processing that has to happen in your game, and you can interpolate between sizes in order to present a smooth animation to the user.

Comment: However, this won't work. I tried this method and the fixtures fall behind the actor.